# Magento REST API using PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, magento, magento2

I have generated Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token & Access Token Secret. I'm not going to use OAuth. How can I integrate with PHP so that I can view products or insert product in Magento. I have latest version of Magento 2.x.

Thank You!

Comment: I'm not sure about Magento 2, but I'm pretty sure you *have to* use OAuth if you're using the REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create Integrations for that

> Admin => System => Extensions :: Integrations => Add New Integration

assign Resource Access as per your needs and save

on save the integration you will have followings

- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret
- Access Token
- Access Token Secret

you can use **Access Token** for REST API Calls in header

```
Authorization : Bearer nptblbtpbh5oj2aag1sdjvvwsm******
```

REST API Calls URL : http://yourMagento2.store/index.php/rest/

Magento2 Rest API Reference : http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/

you need to prefix all calls with the method you want to use

for ex: Admin Token URL :

```
http://yourMagento2.store/index.php/rest/V1/categories

Method : GET
```

**Header**

```
Authorization: Bearer nptblbtpbh5oj2aag1sdjvvwsm******
```

it will return JSON containing Category TREE

Comment: I have already generating API part. Where can I find docs ? and what the URL should be ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I tried using this : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-ProductCategories but not working :( It is working fine for magento 1.9 but not for 2.x. Any official docs for 2.x ?

Comment: for the full API reference you can refer to http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html